# Qual a diferença entre EmbeddedId e IdClass no Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Eu já li na documentação do Hibernate 5.0 que você pode implementar chaves primárias compostas usando duas formas.

A primeira delas é usando a anotação `@IdClass` e imitando os atributos da IdClass na classe original.

A outra é usando a anotação `@EmbeddedId`, onde você pode criar uma classe interna/aninhada e incluir uma referência a ela na classe original.

Existe alguma diferença maior entre as duas formas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

São duas formas de fazer a representação da chave composta na entidade.

Digamos que você tem uma tabela `parametro`, entidade `Parametro` e sua chave composta é `nome` e `empresa`. A tabela pode ser como a exemplificada abaixo:

| nome | empresa | valor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| taxa | 56 | 3.44 |

O `@EmbeddedId` cria uma abstração dentro da entidade que não existe na tabela do banco de dados. Ela une as informações que compõem a chave composta sob uma mesma variável. Veja, respectivamente, a classe que representa a chave composta e a entidade mapeando ela com `@EmbeddedId`:

```
 @Embeddable
 class ParametroId {
      private String nome;
      private Integer empresa;
 }

 @Entity
 class Parametro {
      @EmbeddedId
      private ParametroId parametroId;
 }
```

Veja agora que este formato de mapeamento é refletido nas consultas. Exemplo em JPQL:

```
SELECT p FROM Parametro p where p.parametroId = :parametroId
```

Analisando a consulta acima, perceba que não existe uma coluna `parametroId` na tabela `parametro` do banco de dados, o que pode ser um pouco estranho ao fazer consultas em JPQL, onde uma das vantagens dela é ser parecida com o SQL. E se for fazer uma consulta apenas por `nome` ou `empresa`, a discrepância entre o SQL gerado e o JPQL fica ainda mais evidente. Veja:

```
SELECT p FROM Parametro p where p.parametroId.empresa = :empresa
```

Já o `@IdClass` não envolve a criação de uma nova classe com as chaves da tabela. Assim, as consultas ficam mais próximas do SQL gerado:

```
SELECT p FROM Parametro p where p.nome = :nome AND p.empresa = :empresa;
```

Porém, esta flexibilidade faz com que o conceito de "chave composta" fique oculta no código. Com `@EmbeddedId` o uso da chave composta acaba sendo mais natural no código, principalmente se estiver usando o `CrudRepository` do Spring, onde para usar o `@IdClass` você [precisa simular uma classe `@EmbeddedId`](https://github.com/mmnaseri/spring-data-mock/issues/141#issuecomment-233483216).

Answer (score 5):

Há pessoas que advogam o fato de que mapeamentos com `@EmbeddedId` são mais expressivos e claros, porque você consegue acessar diretamente a classe que possui a chave composta, algo que não é possível com `@IdClass`. Por exemplo:

Mapeamento com `@EmbeddedId`:

```
@Embeddable class EmployeeId { 
  String name;
  LocalDate dataOfBirth;
}

@Entity class Employee {
  @EmbeddedId EmployeeId employeeId;
  ...
}
```

Mapeamento com `@IdClass`:

```
class EmployeeId { 
   String name;
   LocalDate dateOfBirth;
}

@Entity class Employee {
@IdClass(EmployeeId.class);
   @Id String name;
   @Id LocalDate dateOfBirth;
   ...
}
```

Em queries HQL, na maioria das vezes, saber que determinado campo faz parte de uma chave composta e não é um campo simples da entidade faz toda a diferença. Isso, só o `@EmbeddedId` proporciona. Exemplos de `queries` de ambos:

```
select e.name from Employee e //@IdClass

select e.employeeId.name from Employee e //@EmbeddedId
```

A segunda `query`, de cara, transmite bem mais informações sobre o mapeamento.

Um outro exemplo de diferença entre `queries` de um e de outro para atingir o mesmo resultado, no caso usando o operador `IN`:

```
//com @EmbeddedId
FROM Entity WHERE id IN :ids

//com @IdClass
FROM Entity WHERE idPartA = :idPartA0 AND idPartB = :idPartB0 .... OR idPartA = :idPartAN AND idPartB = :idPartBN
```

Por outro lado, há casos de uso bem específicos em que o `@IdClass` é uma solução bem mais fácil de se usar. Por exemplo, quando uma das chaves compostas é também um relacionamento:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(PhonePK.class)
public class Phone {

    @Id
    private String type;

    @ManyToOne
    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name="OWNER_ID", referencedColumnName="EMP_ID")
    private Employee owner;
    ...
}

public class PhonePK {
    private String type;
    private long owner;
    ...
}
```

Resumindo, é questão de necessidade de negócio e clareza de código que vão definir qual mapeamento você vai utilizar. Na prática, ambos fazem, e muito bem, a mesma coisa.